# My DML queries are not affecting row in Oracle DB?

Tags: java, spring, database, oracle

I have an application that works as expected and I can insert/update the rows through application.
But when I connect to my oracle database through SQL Developer and tried to run the UPDATE query, I get message that 1 row is updated. while the row is not updated.

Also the user I used to connect oracle database is same for both Application and SQL Developer with having insert and update privileges.

I feel a transparency Layer is implemented in oracle database that blocks the direct query execution.
Can anyone knows how this feature is implemented or which oracle product is configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After DML, you will have to `commit` the transaction to make actual changes in the database.

Without `commit`, you will see the changed data in current session but other sessions will not be able to see that changes. Or you can say, it is not actually changed in database too  without `commit`.

Comment: I have run the update query and i get response as "1 row is affected."

immediately i run the select query to see my changes but the changes were not applied.

Comment: the select query is run in same session and i should have see the changes. Also i don't get any error or notice that the operation is blocked by any trigger.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with Oracle is that most SQL applications that connect to oracle do not auto-commit (make permanent changes to the database record when you run a DML) when auto-commit option is off.  Any DML run should be followed by the ***commit;*** command.
You can turn on auto-commit in SQL Developer by going to the Menu item Tools > Preferences > Advanced > then "check" the auto commit option if you do not want to run the command every time.